# WordPress echo image and url

Tags: php, image, wordpress, href, permalinks

I'm trying to get a dynamic image to display the image defined on a variable, and also to have the link to that url to be the same as the permalink for the item.

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'"><img src="'.$thumburl.'" alt="Status"></a>';
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with that code?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> code use on your loop:
> ```

```
<?php 
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'thumbnail');   
?>

<?php  echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$image_url[0].'"
 alt="Status"></a>';    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `get_permalink()` instead of `the_permalink()`

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$thumburl.'" alt="Status"></a>';
```

[get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

> Returns the permalink to a post or page for use in PHP. It does NOT display the permalink and can be used outside of The Loop. On failure returns false.

[the_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink):

> Displays the URL for the permalink to the post currently being processed in The Loop. This tag must be within The Loop, and is generally used to display the permalink for each post, when the posts are being displayed. Since this template tag is limited to displaying the permalink for the post that is being processed, you cannot use it to display the permalink to an arbitrary post on your weblog. Refer to get_permalink() if you want to get the permalink for a post, given its unique post id.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a ton!  I knew it had to be something tiny like that.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to tell us what the problem is. I suppose that the image is not displayed. The code is OK.
Double check the image path stored in $thumburl. Inspect the element in a browser to check that img's source and post it here. Are you using an absolute path in $thumburl?

Comment: My apologies.  The permalink doesn't seem to be part of the link.  The image also links to the homepage instead of the permalink.   The $thumburl path is absolute and the image itself works fine, its just the link that doesn't work.

http://postimg.org/image/w1vj02qlt/